# How to split input arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the below code which expects 1 or more file names as arguments.

It works for one file but now the input arguments can be multiple files such as `1.json 2.json 3.json`.

How can I handle this?

```
import sys
import os
import json

inFile = sys.argv[1]


print(inFile)

with open(inFile, 'r') as file:
    try:
        json_data = json.load(file)
    except ValueError as e:
        print "Invalid Json supplied:%s" % e
        exit(1)
    else:
        print "json file ok"
        print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `argv` is a list (parsing the passed arg string is done for you), you can iterate over it, skipping `argv[0]` which is the program filename:

```
import json
import sys

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(arg, "r") as file:
        try:
            json_data = json.load(file)
            print "json file ok"
            print json_data
        except ValueError as e:
            print "Invalid JSON supplied: %s" % e
            exit(1)
```

You may want to put this data into a list so you can do something with it in your program:

```
import json
import sys

data = []

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(arg, "r") as file:
        try:
            data.append(json.load(file))                
        except ValueError as e:
            print "Invalid JSON supplied: %s" % e
            exit(1)
```